# JNI, Garbage collection and Pointers- Java/C++ who should do what?

Tags: java, c++, garbage-collection, java-native-interface

We have the concept of pointers in C++. Now if we allocate some memory in C++ and pass it on to Java as an object reference(using JNI) then who should be and who will be freeing it.

Will it be

1.)The Garbage collector does it automatically in Java?

2.)We need to explicitly do a delete on the pointer in the wrapped JNI class finalize method?

3.)Or we should just forget finalize(as finalizers cannot be trusted) and it is responsibility of Java to call a C++ code which deletes the object

4.)Or is there some way to deallocate the memory directly in Java itself (not sure how Java intreprets a C++ pointer inorder to delete it)?

What is the best practice for doing this and vice versa(when we pass objects from Java to C++)?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> We have the concept of pointers in C++. Now if we allocate some memory in C++ and pass it on to Java as an object reference(using JNI) then who should be and who will be freeing it.

The best strategy is usually to have the allocator also be the one to free the data.

> 1.)The Garbage collector does it automatically in Java?

The problem with this is you don't know when, if ever it will run.

> 2.)We need to explicitly do a delete on the pointer in the wrapped JNI class finalize method?

Better to have a release() method in Java rather than imply that C++ has to delete it.  You may want C++ to recycle the memory.

> 3.)Or we should just forget finalize(as finalizers cannot be trusted) and it is responsibility of Java to call a C++ code which deletes the object

If you mean, allocate the memory in Java and pass it to C++ to populate.  This is my preference.

I would use can use ByteBuffer.allocateDirect() and you can call `((DirectBuffer) buffer).cleaner().clean();` to clean it up deterministically.

This can make recycling the memory simpler, possibly the same buffer can be used for the life of the application.

Comment: +1 definitely the allocator should be the one to release, and allocating Java-side (if possible) is "cleaner".

Comment: I agree its cleaner, esp if Java calls C++ rather than they other way around.

Comment: For point number 2, the release method in Java will call the C++ method which will actually delete the object? How can Java directly release memory allocated in C++?

Comment: You can use Unsafe.freeMemory if the memory was `malloc`ed. But like I say that's not the best option.

Comment: As long as it's only memory we are freeing I usually just write a small java wrapper around the c++ resource and use the finalizer to call the release method there - extremely simple and fool proof. The only problem are resources we want to release deterministically, but then we have the same problem and solutions for normal Java as well.

Comment: If you use a direct ByteBuffer you can call `((DirectBuffer) buffer).cleaner().clean();` to clean it up deterministically.

Comment: Sure, or just calling the native release function will also be deterministically - the problem is deciding WHEN I can call the function. But then in my experience I never had complicated scenarios where just calling `close()` wouldn't have worked (now much nicer with java7 syntax). And most of the time I don't hold resources in my C++ code that need to be cleaned up deterministically anyhow so I go for the simplest solution.

Comment: `I go for the simplest solution.` agreed, its more likely to work that way.;)

Comment: Exactly - I can't screw up (well not that easily at least) if I let the JVM figure out all the hard parts ;) Though I still tend to try to outsmart myself - it's just much more interesting that way! (bad habit that I know)

Comment: @Voo, put another way, its more likely to work if you use something already tested. ;)