How to clean up C++ objects when their Kotlin wrapper objects are no longer referenced (minSdkVersion 24)?
I'm a beginner in Kotlin and currently working on integrating a C++ library into an Android app written in Kotlin. To achieve this, I am implementing JNI and Kotlin wrappers for the C++ library.
In my design, Kotlin objects hold references to C++ objects. I want to ensure that the memory used by the C++ objects is properly deallocated when all references to the corresponding Kotlin objects are removed.
I learned about java.lang.ref.Cleaner, which can register cleanup tasks to run when an object is no longer referenced. However, my app's minSdkVersion is set to 24, and Cleaner is only available from API level 33.
Could you suggest an alternative approach to achieve this cleanup? Essentially, I'm looking for a mechanism that automatically triggers a cleanup task for an object when it's no longer referenced, similar to how std::shared_ptr in C++ calls the destructor when its reference count drops to zero.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/8926787/16034206 This seems like it could be helpful if you want to rethink your implementation

Cleaner is implemented in terms of the following concepts:

phantom references, which exist solely to detect when an object is no longer reachable through the usual means, and
reference queues, which allow you to wait for phantom references to expire.

The PhantomReference constructor returns a new phantom reference for a given object associated with a given ReferenceQueue. You can then associate the PhantomReference with a separate cleanup action. Finally, have a thread block on ReferenceQueue#remove() and run the cleanup action associated with that PhantomReference.
You cannot read the object because it is already gone from memory when remove() is called, so it is your responsibility to make sure to make the cleanup action is idempotent, or that you disarm the cleaning action when the object is removed.
